# How to change camera's aspect ratio in IOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, camera

I working on ios app. My application can take photo, I need change camera's aspect ratio to 1:1.

How to change the aspect ratio on iOS ?

Comment: You can't adjust the aspect ratio of the camera to 1:1. However you can crop the photo after you take it.

Comment: I think you are right, i didn't find any other way.